# How to convert a two column csv file to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv:

```
Name1    Name2

JSMITH    J Smith
ASMITH    A Smith
```

How can I read it into a dictionary so that the output is

```
dict = {'JSMITH':'J Smith', 'ASMITH': 'A Smith'}
```

I have used:

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data_dict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

but it gives me

```
{'Name1': ['JSMITH','ASMITH'],'Name2': ['J Smith', 'A Smith']}
```

I am then hoping to use it in a `map` function in `pandas` such as:

```
df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].replace(data_dict, regex=True)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick if you always have only two columns:

```
dict(df.itertuples(False,None))
```

Or make it a `pandas.Series` and use `to_dict`:

```
df.set_index("Name1")["Name2"].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'ASMITH': 'A Smith', 'JSMITH': 'J Smith'}
```

Note that if you need a mapper to a `pd.Series.replace`, `Series` works just as fine as a `dict`.

```
s = df.set_index("Name1")["Name2"]
df["Name1"].replace(s, regex=True)

0    J Smith
1    A Smith
Name: Name1, dtype: object
```

Which also means that you can remove `to_dict` and cut some overhead:

```
large_df = df.sample(n=100000, replace=True)

%timeit large_df.set_index("Name1")["Name2"]
# 4.76 ms ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit large_df.set_index("Name1")["Name2"].to_dict()
# 20.2 ms ± 976 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: ah yes, great. Thanks very much! so you are saying i can use `df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].replace(series, regex=True)`?

Comment: @SOK I've added some example to demonstrate ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `dict`

```py
dict(zip(df.Name1, df.Name2))
```